# Can I remove symlinks without deleting the files?

Tags: macos, file, symlink, hidden-files

I was following the **Dotfiles** exercises in the [CLE](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/command-line/) MIT Missing Semester course and I messed up. I created a `dotfiles` directory and moved all the dotfiles in my home folder to that directory, then I ran the following code from `dotfiles`:

```
for filename in dotfiles
do 
ln -s $filename dotfiles/$filename
end
```

Basically, I symlinked everything in the wrong direction. Now all those dotfiles in my home directory are useless, and all the dotfiles in the `dotfiles` directory are pointless because they don't actually point to anything.
Is there any solution to this problem that doesn't involve deleting all my dotfiles and reinstalling everything? I'm using macOS Monterey.

I tried using the `unlink` command but that just deletes the files. I'm looking for a solution where I can keep all my dotfiles and just remove the symlinks.

Comment: The posted code will just create a single symlink `dotfiles/dotfiles` that points at itself.  So just remove that (one) symlink, and do whatever it was you intended to do.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I should have made it clear that “dotfiles” in the posted code is just pseudo code for a list of all the dotfiles generated with a command like “find . -name “\..*””, not literally the word dotfiles.